# Is there a simpler way to pass a BufReader to a function?

Tags: rust, file-io

To read the bytes of a PNG file, I want to create a function called `read_8_bytes` which will read the next 8 bytes in the file each time it's called.

```
fn main(){
   let png = File::open("test.png").expect("1");
   let mut png_reader = BufReader::new(png);
   let mut byteBuffer: Vec<u8> = vec![0;8];
   png_reader.read_exact(&mut byteBuffer).expect("2"); 
}
```

This works fine and if I keep calling `read_exact` from main I can read the next 8 bytes. I tried to create a function to do this and the solution just seems needlessly complicated. I'm wondering if there is a better way.

I thought I have to pass the BufReader to the function, but due to how Rust works this makes things complicated and I end up working out I need to do something like:

```
fn read_eight_bytes<R: BufRead>(fd: &mut R)
```

This compiles but I'm not happy because I don't understand why this needed to be done and seems complex. Is there a simple way of  having a function I can pass a file descriptor type thing to and have it store the position like in C without having to do this?

Comment: Its not clear to me what part of this is "complicated", it looks like a perfectly reasonable function.

Comment: Agreed, other than maybe doing `fn read_eight_bytres(fd: &mut impl BufRead)` your fn seems totally fine to me.

Comment: i found it complex because i would expect coming from c to be able to pass a reference to BufReader to the function and use that to reference the data, but i have to use a generic and use BufRead .. loganfsmyth ive not seen that before can i declare a function like you said and have it work?

Answer (score 5):

Looking at your question, I think you are trying to say that you are confused as to why the `<R: BufRead>` is necessary or furthermore why this even works.

In your example, this *generic* is not strictly necessary. One could implement the function you describe like so:

```rust
use std::{fs, io};

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut file = fs::File::open("./path/to/file")?;
    let bytes = read_eight_bytes(&mut file)?;
    println!("{:?}", bytes);
    Ok(())
}

fn read_eight_bytes(file: &mut fs::File) -> io::Result<[u8; 8]> {
    use io::Read;

    let mut bytes = [0; 8];
    file.read_exact(&mut bytes)?;
    Ok(bytes)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3bacdc1815521affc34f652395bef373)

This is perfectly valid and hopefully should make sense.

But then, why does `fn read_eight_bytes<R: BufRead>(file: &mut R) -> [u8; 8]` work? First of all, I assume you understand the following concepts:

- [Generics](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-01-syntax.html)
- [Traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html)

Given an understanding of the above concepts, you should know that this syntax means that the function `read_eight_bytes` is a *generic function* with a generic type named `R`. You should then also understand that the *generic* has a *trait bound*, requiring the type `R` to implement `BufRead`. And that this function takes a parameter which is a mutable reference to the variable `file`, which is of the type `R`.

Now taking a look at the definition of [`BufRead`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html): we see that it contains several functions. But surprisingly there is no `read_exact` function! Why does a function like this compile?

```
use std::{fs, io};
use io::BufRead;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let file = fs::File::open("./path/to/file")?;
    let mut reader = io::BufReader::new(file);
    let bytes = read_eight_bytes(&mut reader)?;
    println!("{:?}", bytes);
    Ok(())
}

fn read_eight_bytes<R: BufRead>(reader: &mut R) -> io::Result<[u8; 8]> {
    let mut bytes = [0; 8];
    reader.read_exact(&mut bytes)?;
    Ok(bytes)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=65c7de201a868f33508a442271973a81)

> Note: I have altered the return type to `io::Result<...>`. This is considered to be a better practice compared to `unwrap`ing every `Result`.
> I have also changed the function call to use a `BufReader` because `BufReader` implements `BufRead` whilst `File` does not. I will cover the difference a little further below.

The reason this works is because `BufRead` is a [Super Trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#using-supertraits-to-require-one-traits-functionality-within-another-trait). This means that any type that implements `BufRead` must also implement `Read` too. And thus it must have the `read_exact` function!

Given our function never requires the functions on `BufRead` we could change the trait bound to only require `Read`:

```
use std::{fs, io};
use io::Read;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let file = fs::File::open("./path/to/file")?;
    let mut reader = io::BufReader::new(file);
    let bytes = read_eight_bytes(&mut reader)?;
    println!("{:?}", bytes);
    Ok(())
}

fn read_eight_bytes<R: Read>(reader: &mut R) -> io::Result<[u8; 8]> {
    let mut bytes = [0; 8];
    reader.read_exact(&mut bytes)?;
    Ok(bytes)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=28ce98ef78c84d3f152860b922a08497)

Now here is something interesting about this change. The `read_eight_bytes` function can now be called in (at least) two different ways:

```
use std::{fs, io};
use io::Read;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let mut file = fs::File::open("./path/to/file")?;
    let bytes = read_eight_bytes(&mut file)?;
    println!("{:?}", bytes);

    let file = fs::File::open("./path/to/file")?;
    let mut reader = io::BufReader::new(file);
    let bytes = read_eight_bytes(&mut reader)?;
    println!("{:?}", bytes);

    Ok(())
}

fn read_eight_bytes<R: Read>(reader: &mut R) -> io::Result<[u8; 8]> {
    let mut bytes = [0; 8];
    reader.read_exact(&mut bytes)?;
    Ok(bytes)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c55abc71b16dacac31e52ada03f2ef45)

Why is this? This is because both [`File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#impl-Read) and [`BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html#impl-Read) implement the `Read` trait. And thus can both be used with the `read_eight_bytes` function!

So then why would someone want to use either `File` or `BufReader` over the other?

Well the [`BufReader`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufReader.html#) documentation explains this:

> The BufReader struct adds buffering to any reader.
>
> It can be excessively inefficient to work directly with a Read
> instance. For example, every call to read on TcpStream results in a
> system call. A BufReader performs large, infrequent reads on the
> underlying Read and maintains an in-memory buffer of the results.
>
> BufReader can improve the speed of programs that make small and
> repeated read calls to the same file or network socket. It does not
> help when reading very large amounts at once, or reading just one or a
> few times. It also provides no advantage when reading from a source
> that is already in memory, like a Vec.

Now, remember how before we wrote this function just for the `File` type? The primary reason why one would want to write it with generics would be such that a caller can make the choice presented above. This is common practice in libraries where such a choice really does matter. However, generics come at the cost of increased [compile times](https://matklad.github.io/2021/09/04/fast-rust-builds.html) (when used excessively) and increased code complexity.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this,  i guess its just a part of rust ill have to learn to understand in some ways C is easier to write this stuff, but ill keep working through exercises, ive done the full rust by example and other work throughs and honestly traits are the one thing i dont really understand 100%

Comment: Great to hear the answer was helpful :) Good luck on your rust learning journey! By the way, for other resources (on traits and more) I can recommend anything linked on https://www.rust-lang.org/learn especially "the book".